# Determine vendor specific versions of android from cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, device

I'm posting this because after thoroughly researching this, I had to read through the code on a plugin to determine the answer.

To determine if a device is samsung specific ( any of the galaxy series ) for android, cordova-plugin-device is the correct plugin to reference, but their README.md does not mention the correct property to look at.

`device.manufacturer` will be 'samsung' when the device is a samsung galaxy device.

Disclaimer : Its not in the readme, but if you look under the www folder of the plugin, you'll see that `device.manufacturer` is set. I can't testify that its accurate with Apple, Windows, Tizen, or other devices, but for Android devices, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: and the question is? if you want to auto answer your own question, then make a question, answer it and mark it as accepted

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the heads up @jcesarmobile I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the plugin www for cordova-plugin-device to access any properties that may not be available in ReadMe.md from that cordova plugin.

device.manufacturer is the one I was looking for in this instance, but there are others available.